# Issue with Python while loop not ending

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I have an issue with my python code to make beeping noises.
It just does an infinite loop of beeps even though it should stop.

```
import winsound
import time
z = 1
while z == 1:
    b = input('Enter number of beeps required')
    print(b)
    a = input('Is this number correct?')
    if a == "yes":
        print('Python shall use this number')
        z = 2
    if a == "no":
        b = input('Enter number of beeps required')
x = 1
y = -1
while x == 1: 
    freq = 1500
    dur = 50
    winsound.Beep(freq,dur)
    y += 1
    if y == b:
        x = 2
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Sorry about the terrible organisation of this post i was rushed and didn't edit it correctly

Comment: Why this complicated check of verifying if the input is correct? Just ask the user and use this number (i.e., convert it to one). If he enters gibberish, its his problem.

Comment: I took the liberty to reformat your code in accordance with the [PEP-8 (Style Guide for Python code)](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You should read and honor that as well to make your programs easier to read.

Comment: Help for debugging: If you enter the line `print((y, b))` before the `if y == b:` line, you'll get a tuple of the `repr()` of both values printed. This shows you the difference (string vs. int).

Comment: BTW, are you allergic to the [`break` statement](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Python 3.x, [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string object.

Comparing string object with int always return False.

```
>>> '1' == 1
False
```

You should convert string object to int before compare them:

```
b = int(b)
```

BTW, it's better to use following instead of `while` loop:

```
for i in range(int(b)):
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `input()` on Python 3 returns a string, so `b` will be a string, and therefore `y == b` will never be `True`.

Use

```
b = int(input('Enter number of beeps required'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
b=input ('Enter number of beeps required')
```

to

```
b=int(input ('Enter number of beeps required'))
```

You are reading `b` as string and comparing it against an `int` in

```
if y == b:
```

which will never be `True`. Thats why your code is infinitely looping.